# S3 and Google Drive in Backup Storage?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm starting my first contact with the aws experience. And I have the following situation where I work:
All of our file storage is done on the google drive (with a GSuite account). But we found that Drive has a download and storage limit per account.

I wonder if for this backup and storage of files the S3 is the most suitable? Because we are wanting to use the service.Besides that we want to keep these files stored

Thank you!

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', I recommend you ask at: https://reddit.com/r/cloud or https://www.reddit.com/r/aws